# .NET MVC 4 Content Negotiation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, content-negotiation

I have a web service which is implemented in C# using .NET MVC 4, but for some reason they are always returning the data in XML format although I am sending an Accept: application/json header. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance

**Update**: The controller code looks like this

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetData()
{
     ...
     DashboardInformation d = new DashboardInformation()
     {
            Name = "Test",
            employees = employees,
            shortcuts = shortcuts,
            notes = dashboardNoteList,
            timeEntries = dashboardTimeList,
            timeTracker = timeTracker,
            timeTrackerFromDate = ToUnixTimestamp(fromDate),
            timeTrackerToDate = ToUnixTimestamp(toDate),
            timeSummary = timeSummary,
            userInfo = uInfo
     };
     return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, d);
}
```

**Update 2**: Raw request and response

Request

```
GET /RestService/api/Dashboard/GetData HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko)         Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Referer: http://xxx/Firm4.0/dashboard.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 06 Nov 2012 19:01:59 GMT
Content-Length: 3610
...
```

Comment: Do you mean you're using WebApi?

Comment: Sorry, I am a .NET newbie so, yes. My controller is extending ApiController.

Comment: Have you tried it calling the GET directly through Fiddler? http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ or Curl? Do you get the same issue? Presumably you are using JQuery for this call? If so can you share the calling code too? Which version of WebApi are you using - just checking it isn't the Beta or earlier...

Comment: Actually, I am using RestClient firefox plugin for this one, although it is not working with jquery either.

Answer (score 0):

I will need more information to diagnose your problem

1. Has the set of default formatters been modified in any way?  For example, in App_Start\WebApi.Config.cs:

   ```
       config.Formatters.Clear();
       config.Formatters.Add(...);
   ```
2. How does your action in your ApiController that you are trying to call looks like?
3. Can you provide us with your raw request and response message?

Comment: I added both the Controller and the raw request and response data to the question. About question 1, no they are not modified as far as I know (searched through the project for config.Formatters). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. There was a custom IContentNegotiator implementation which was always returning a XmlMediaTypeFormatter. Thanks everybody for the help.